# Get all categories of post in Laravel

Tags: laravel, categories

I create a table post__post_category_relations to save categories of post.

```
Schema::create('post__post_category_relations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsinged();
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsinged();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

At blade template edit post, I want show list categories of post.

In Post model I wrote:

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsTo(PostCategoryRelations::class,'id','post_id','category_id');
}
```

But it only return one category. Can you show me how to show all categories? Thank so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks similar to [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) approach between posts and categories. And a junction table which connects post and category table should have `post_id`, `category_id` and other columns are not required like `id` , `timestamps()` i guess you won't be using them in your application.
Migration would minimize to

```
Schema::create('post__post_category_relations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsinged();
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsinged();

});
```

For many to many you can add definitions in your models like

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'post__post_category_relations', 'post_id');
    }
}


class Category extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post__post_category_relations', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

If you still want to keep other columns from junction table `post__post_category_relations` you can access them by defining as pivot attributes in your model like

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'post__post_category_relations', 'post_id')
        ->withPivot('id','cols')
        ->as('post__post_category_relation_cols');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It works fine! Can you tell me why I shouldn't add timestamps and id columns.

Comment: @justcntt will you be using them in your app? simple reason to keep them or remove them it depends on your project requirements, Generally in many to many relationship a junction table has 2 attributes to relate 2 entities

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, Thank you, I understand.

Comment: Hello @M Khailid Junaid, Can you help me?Example: One category name is 'Funny', this has many posts. 10 posts only has one category is 'Funny'. If I delete category 'Funny', 10 posts will not has category. But I want when I delete category, 10 posts will move to category 'Uncategory' (id = 1). Can you tell me how to? Thank buddy!

Comment: @justcntt its better if you ask new question then SO users including me can have a better look on your query

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, Can you go to my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563704/move-post-to-uncategorized-category-when-deleted-old-category-of-post-in-larav