# Move post to 'Uncategorized' Category when deleted old Category of post in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I created a table to save post and category relationship.

```
Schema::create('post__post_category_relations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsinged();
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsinged();
    });
```

If I delete a category, I want posts of this category will move to 'Uncategorized' Category (with ID = 1) if post only have one a category.

This is my script at CategoryController:

```
 public function destroy(Category $category)
{

    $this->category->destroy($category);

    foreach($category->posts as $post){
        if(count($post->categories) <= 1){
            PostCategoryRelations::where('post_id',$post->id)->update(['category_id' => 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

And Category Model:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post__post_category_relations', 'category_id');
}
```

And Post Model:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'post__post_category_relations', 'post_id');
}
```

It working but I think it is'nt optimize. Because I must use the loop to find post only have one category. If I have 1 million posts, will very slow when I want delete a category. Can you show me better ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick:

```
$postsOfCategory = $category->posts()->withCount('categories')->get();
$postsWithOneCategory = $postsOfCategory->filter(function ($post) {
    return $post->categories_count <= 1;
});
$postsIDs = $postsWithOneCategory->pluck(['id'])->toArray();

PostCategoryRelations::whereIn('post_id', $postsIDs)->update(['category_id' => 1]);
```

First you get the posts with count of their related categories in a single query.
Then you filter only the posts with 1 or 0 categories. Finally you get their IDs and update them in the DB with a single query.